# Update table view data based on row component selected in picker view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite, uipickerview

I have an app,where I need to save a reminder in one page and in other display the saved reminder.I have done it successfully using sqlite3

In the view reminder page,the user would have 3 options to view,view all which I have already implemented,view monthly that contains picker view with 12 months,view group

I have found out the query for retrieving all the reminders in a particular month,say for month december,I have retrieved using the following query:

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from reminders WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-31'"];
```

Before entering in to view monthly page(controller),there is a month picker view as I have mentioned earlier,I know that we can have separate view controller pages for displaying the data of 12 months,but the code becomes hectic.Hence I want the table view to get updated automatically based on month selected in picker view(row component).

How can I do this,can any one please help me out with your valuable suggestions!

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: @gideon If you know any answer,can you please suggest me,thanks for editing anyway :)

Comment: sorry buddy, I know nothing about the iphone, just edited your edited your question so it's more likely to be answered :)

Comment: @gideon Oh,that's k....thanks once again for editing,bye tc :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer for the question in the following link:

[Get selected value of a picker view that is present in different view and use the string in some other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708543/get-selected-value-of-a-picker-view-that-is-present-in-different-view-and-use-th)

Thank you all :)