# How to update table view data based on row component selected in picker view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipickerview

I have an app,where I need to save a reminder in one page and in other display the saved reminder.I have done it successfully using sqlite3!

In the view reminder page,the user would have 3 options to view,view all which I have already implemented,view group that contains reminders of 4 groups.Because they are just 4 groups,I have created 4 view controllers for 4 unique groups.Just simply using the following query which worked perfect:

```
 NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from reminders WHERE grp = 'Friends'"];
```

But I have a problem with view monthly page which contains 12 row components in picker view for the user to select,i.e all the 12 months of the year:

I have found out the query for retrieving all the reminders in a particular month,say for month december,I have retrieved using the following query:

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from reminders WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-31'"];
```

Before entering in to view monthly page(controller),there is a month picker view as I have mentioned earlier,I know that we can have separate view controller pages for displaying the data of 12 months as I did in the case of view group reminders,but the code becomes hectic.Hence I want the table view to get updated automatically based on month selected in picker view(row component).

I found out a similar question,but the question was unanswered!

[Update table view data based on row component selected in picker view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633426/update-table-view-data-based-on-row-component-selected-in-picker-view)

I tried to create an instance of the class controller where picker view is present for the view controller where data is getting displayed:

ERViewEditController *viewEditController;

and while retrieving I used the following code:

```
if(viewEditController.monthPicker selectedRowInComponent:0)
{
sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from reminders WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'"];
sql_stmt = [sqlQuery UTF8String];
}

else if(viewEditController.monthPicker selectedRowInComponent:1)
{
sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from reminders WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-31'"];
sql_stmt = [sqlQuery UTF8String];
}
```

etc... and so on for all months then used the following code for display:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB, sql_stmt, -1, &statament, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statament) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {             
                ReminderClass *remin = [[ReminderClass alloc]init];

                remin.Name = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 1)]autorelease];
                remin.Event = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 2)]autorelease];
                remin.Date = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 3)]autorelease];

                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remin.Date];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
                NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
                remin.Date = dateVal;

                [self.monthArray addObject:remin];
                [remin release];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statament);
        }
```

Nothing is getting displayed now :(

How can I achieve the requirement,can any one please help me out with your valuable suggestions!

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer in this link:

[Get selected value of a picker view that is present in different view and use the string in some other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708543/get-selected-value-of-a-picker-view-that-is-present-in-different-view-and-use-th)

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

You should just call reloadData method.

if in .h fileyou are having an object of TableView

```
UITableView *table;
```

Then when you want to update your table you should write,

```
[table reloadData];
```

Comment: Yeah,I am aware of how to reload the data of a table.But my requirement is:I have a picker view with 12 months.Now when I select a row,it will navigate to a view controller where the reminders corresponding to that month is displayed.

But I can't have 12 view controllers for displaying the reminders of 12 corresponding months.So I want the table view to get automatically updated based on selected month.So is there any way for linking the picker view row component with table view data...
Please help me in that aspect.Please see the question once again...
Thanks for the answer and concern :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the Row of PickerView
2. Save it into String
3. Access this string into new View Controller, where your UITableView delegates methods are implemented
4. `cell.textLabel.text = str`; where str is the string which you selected on your pickerView
5. In a method of new View Controller, where you are accessing string, write a line of code    `[table reloadData];`

Comment: Thanks for the answer,will implement and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Debug you code by inserting debug Point at line.

```
[self.monthArray addObject:remin];
```

then,you should write the following code to conform that either your array is empty or having required values.

```
for(int i=0;i<[self.monthArray count];i++)
{
NSLog("Array ids :%@",[self.monthArray ObjectAtIndex:i])
}
```

if it prints the correct values in console, then you should write the following line in the delegate method cellForRowAtIndex.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: thank for the answer,it is displaying in console as :

Array ids :<ReminderClass: 0x7183250>
2012-01-02 19:11:26.083 EventsReminder[6450:207] Array ids :<ReminderClass: 0x7183250>
2012-01-02 19:11:26.083 EventsReminder[6450:207] Array ids :<ReminderClass: 0x5c20a00>
2012-01-02 19:11:26.084 EventsReminder[6450:207] Array ids :<ReminderClass: 0x7183250>
2012-01-02 19:11:26.085 EventsReminder[6450:207] Array ids :<ReminderClass: 0x5c20a00>
2012-01-02 19:11:26.085 EventsReminder[6450:207] Array ids :<ReminderClass: 0x7183270>

Comment: I found out the answer in this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708543/get-selected-value-of-a-picker-view-that-is-present-in-different-view-and-use-th

Thanks khalid for every thing :)